# CI/CD in Azure to trigger releases to environments based off the branch code was checked in to

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, release-management

We are trying to create pipelines in DevOps so that if we update the development branch it will trigger a release to development, if we update the QA branch it will trigger a release to QA, and if we update master it will trigger a release to prod (pending approval). Problem we're having is that whenever we update any branch it will build a new package just for that branch, but then it will trigger deployments in all environments.

Our Dev and QA branches are really just there to fascilitate deploying to those environments. Our work is done based off of master and then the dev or QA branch is updated with what is essentially master + changes. Though, for a better explenation, we're trying to implement this strategy: https://medium.com/@sairamkrish/git-branching-strategy-for-true-continuous-delivery-eade4435b57e

[image: Release Pipelines]

Comment: Good tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you should configure:

- continous deployment trigger on artifact
  [image]
- artifacts filter on each stage
  [image]
- and pre-deployment approval on Prod stage
  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try.

Comment: @madeFromCode How's your issue going? Is it solved?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT We haven't had time to revisit this task, but will update once we get to work on it again. Thanks for the link in the comment above.